# Zoom in when clicking on a button unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, button, uibutton, zooming

I'm trying to create a zoom in button, in my unity scene
I saw this video, but the 'zoom cam' isn't working.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ACR-W9QZQwE&t=127s&ab_channel=DesignandDeploy
Does anyone know how to do this?

Here is my code and 'lupa' is the button i want to click to do the zoom in

[image]
[image]
[image]
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that [OnMouseDown()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html) isn't getting called. That function has a specific use case, as you can read in the docs. The script might not be attached to the correct collider, etc.
If you want to trigger it from a button, you can - add it to the list of functions triggered by the button's OnClick() through the inspector. Tons of YouTube tutorials for that sort of thing.

Comment: The OnMouseDown() isn't showing up in the list of functions triggered by the button's OnClick()

Comment: That may be because OnMouseDown() already has a builtin unity definition. Try renaming the function to something else and then checking the button's list again.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any other camera in the scene beside the '`zoom cam`', maybe the '`Main Camera`'?

If so, try to disable the other camera by adding the following line

```
GameObject.Find("Main Camera").GetComponent<Camera>().enabled = false;
```

in the script "ZoomIn" at line 17

Comment: I tried to disable the zoom cam and it's still not working... Maybe there's another approach?